# Formatting @HtmlDropDownListFor using htmlAttributes not working when referencing css class

Tags: razor-2, asp.net-mvc-5.1

This is very strange, or maybe I am just not understanding how this works. I have the below code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(dep=>dep.DepartmentId,new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments,"Id","Name"), new {htmlAttributes = new {@class="mySelect"}})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And a style sheet entry:

```
.mySelect {
    width: 5000px;
    border: groove;
}
```

This above combination does not format my drop down list, but if I perform direct formatting it works:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(dep=>dep.DepartmentId,new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments,"Id","Name"), new {@style = "width:500px;border:groove;"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

In addition, if I add the @style to the htmlAttribute section, it does not work, nor does replacing the @style bit with @class="mySelect"...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use direct `@class` without `htmlAttributes`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(dep=>dep.DepartmentId,new SelectList(ViewBag.Departments,"Id","Name"), new { @class="mySelect" })
```